# Double-click DataGridView row?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, double-click

I am using vb.net and DataGridView on a winform.

When a user double-clicks on a row I want to do something with this row. But how can I know whether user clicked on a row or just anywhere in the grid? If I use `DataGridView.CurrentRow` then if a row is selected and user clicked anywhere on the grid the current row will show the selected and not where the user clicked (which in this case would be not on a row and I would want to ignore it).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try the [`CellMouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx) event...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

This will only fire if the user is actually over a cell in the grid.  The `If` check filters out double clicks on the row selectors and headers.

Comment: Worth noting that you can use `e.RowIndex == -1` if you want to run something if you didn't click a row

Answer (score 4):

Use Datagridview DoubleClick Evenet and then Datagrdiview1.selectedrows[0].cell["CellName"] to get value and process.

Below example shows clients record upon double click on selected row.

private void dgvClientsUsage_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (dgvClientsUsage.SelectedRows.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a client");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            string clientName = dgvClientsUsage.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ClientName"].Value.ToString();

            // show selected client Details
            ClientDetails clients = new ClientDetails(clientName);
            clients.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DataGridView.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewhittesttype.aspx) in the double-click handler to find out where the click happened.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [DoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) event of the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc5cbb9z.aspx).  This will at least only fire when the user double clicks in the data grid - you can use the MousePosition to determine what row (if any) the user double clicked on.

Comment: I am using the DoubleClick of the DataGridView. But how can I using the moustposition to infer if the double click was on an actual row?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DoubleClick
    For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
        If DataGridView1.Rows(index).Selected = True Then
            'it is selected
        Else
            'is is not selected
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Keep in mind i could not test this because i diddent have any data to populate my DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Private Sub grdview_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdview.CellDoubleClick

    For index As Integer = 0 To grdview.Rows.Count - 1

        If e.RowIndex = index AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 1 AndAlso grdview.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value = "" Then

            MsgBox("Double Click Message")

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```