# What event is fired when double-clicking a DataGridView row?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double-click DataGridView row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920339/double-click-datagridview-row)

What event is fired when double-clicking a `DataGridView` row?

All I can find is `CellMouseDoubleClick`.

How do I identify the selected row in the event function?  Is it `e.RowIndex`?

Comment: How do I identify the selected row in the event function?

Comment: `e.RowIndex` --   That's the one.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920339.  There are a couple of ways to do it.